# C#/ReportViewer: How to use parameters without specifying parameter names

Tags: c#, reporting-services, reportviewer

I am using a C# solution that uses the ReportViewer control to access our SSRS server reports.

I have been asked if it is possible to code the solution in a way that the parameter names are not specified. I am not sure how to ask this question to be honest.

Currently that solution is used by a handful of reports, so it is simple enough to hard code the parameter names, these parameters are query string parameters.

The solution gets the server URL from the web.config file:

```
// Add the Reporting Server URL
rvSiteMapping.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReportServerUrl"].ToString());
```

The solution gets the report path from a query string parameters named = ReportPath and assigned to a report viewer report path property named ReportPath:

```
//Add the Report Path
rvSiteMapping.ServerReport.ReportPath = Request.QueryString["ReportPath"];
```

These two should remain like this.

What I need to change is the follwoing:

First report takes one parameter named MeetingID,
Second report takes one parameter named RecordID,
Third report takes an array with 3 parameters (each optional)

I specify the name of each parameter for each report.
I am asking if there is a way to achieve the same but without having to specify parameter names, so the solution can be used for any report. Our reports take from 1 to some up to 5 parameters.

**UPDATE Working Code:**

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            try
            {
                rvSiteMapping.Height = Unit.Pixel(Convert.ToInt32(700));
                rvSiteMapping.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ProcessingMode.Remote;
                rvSiteMapping.ShowCredentialPrompts = false;

                if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UseCredentials"].ToString().ToUpper() == "TRUE")
                {
                    rvSiteMapping.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials = new ReportCredential(
                        ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["uname"].ToString(),
                        ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["pwd"].ToString(),
                        ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["domain"].ToString()
                        );
                }

                // Add the Reporting Server URL
                rvSiteMapping.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReportServerUrl"].ToString());
                //Add the Report Path
                rvSiteMapping.ServerReport.ReportPath = Request.QueryString["ReportPath"];

                // see if we have any query string parameters
                if (Request.QueryString.Count > 0)
                {
                    // create the report parameters of the same length
                    List<Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportParameter> p = new List<Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportParameter>();

                    // loop over the query string and use the index to build
                    // your report params based on the key/value
                    for (int idx = 0; idx < Request.QueryString.Count; idx++)
                    {
                        // only add params that are not ReportPath
                        if (Request.QueryString.GetKey(idx) != "ReportPath")
                        {
                            p.Add(new Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportParameter(
                              Request.QueryString.GetKey(idx),
                              Request.QueryString.Get(idx)
                            ));
                        }
                    }
                    // set your report parameters on your server report
                    rvSiteMapping.ServerReport.SetParameters(p);
                }
                rvSiteMapping.ServerReport.Refresh();                }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("General exception. {0}", ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Thank you.
Erasmo Carlos

Comment: Have you tried to call GetReportParameters? It returns a list of parameters. Then you can go through this list and fill the values programmatically. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/reportservice2005.reportingservice2005.getreportparameters?view=sqlserver-2016

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Request.QueryString` is just a collection, so you can make the parameters generic quite easily. I don't have an IDE to hand so my syntax might not be 100% correct - but the general idea would be.

```
 // see if we have any query string parameters
 if (Request.QueryString.Count > 0) {
   // create the report parameters of the same length
   Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportParameter[] p = 
       new Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportParameter[Request.QueryString.Count];

    // loop over the query string and use the index to build
    // your report params based on the key/value
    for (int idx = 0; idx < Request.QueryString.Count; idx++) {
      // only add params that are not ReportPath
      if (Request.QueryString.GetKey(idx) !== "ReportPath") {
        p[idx] = new Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportParameter(
          Request.QueryString.GetKey(idx), 
          Request.QueryString.Get(idx)
        );
      } 
    }   

    // set your report parameters on your server report
    rvSiteMapping.ServerReport.SetParameters(p);
 }
```

This way you can handle any given parameters without having to know the parameter names before hand.

Comment: Hello Fraser, I apologize, I got side-tracked with other projects and this one became lower priority. I am starting to work on this again, and will try to implement your idea. I will post any questions that might come up. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I think this part:    p[idx] = new Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportParameter(Request.QueryString.GetKey(idx),Request.QueryString.Get(idx) < -- this part does not assign the actual value from the parameter obtained tom GetKey(idx), we need something like GetValue(idx)

Comment: The first parameter is the name `Request.QueryString.GetKey(idx)`  the second the value `Request.QueryString.Get(idx)`

Comment: how would the code be, if I need to skip the ReportPath parameter, do not add it as a parameter to be passed to the report as one of the parameters that serve as criteria for the report output? if (Request.QueryString.Get(idx) !== "ReportPath") { then add to report parameter array?
} Thanks

Comment: Exactly as you have it in your comment, see my edit.

Comment: I got it to work! I will put the code that works for my need in the update section. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Are looking at something like this?

```
Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportParameter[] parameters = new Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportParameter[Request.QueryString.Count];
    int i = 0;
    foreach(var val in Request.QueryString)
    {
        parameters[i++]=val;
    }
```

Comment: Hello Akshay, I am starting to work on this task again, I will implement yours and Fraser's idea and get back to you in the next day or two. I apologize for the late response. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I have a question, and I apologize for my lack of expertise on the subject. My aim, is to have the capacity to fetch any report file, by passing the report path in the URL, as a parameter rvSiteMapping.ServerReport.ReportPath = Request.QueryString["ReportPath"];

Comment: That is how I currently achieve that through the Report Viewer  .NET solution.

Comment: I have been able to hard code 1-2 additional query string parameters, most of our reports use RecordID, or RecordID along with MeetingID. I have been able to fetch the correct report, and pass up to 2 hard-coded parameters. But the requirement is different, I need to be able to pass any number of parameters that the actual report requires, perhaps 1, or even none, but always passing ReportPath in the query string.

Comment: From your questions code snippet, you are using the same key as you get from your query string for passing to your report. Instead of hardcoding, Request.QueryString is a collection, you could use query string parameters by looping Request.QueryString, and use its key and value it in your report parameters. If you need/dont need specific query string parameters, you could create an array and include/exclude accordingly.